# How to specify multiple tags using ansibleplaybook Jenkins Plugin

Tags: ansible, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, ansible-2.x

I have a scenario where I need to specify multiple tags in the ansibleplugin. I tried multiple ways to specify the list of tags, but I keep getting the below error. How do I specify multiple tags?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep.setTags() expects class java.lang.String but received class java.util.ArrayList
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:492)
```

```
      ansiColor('xterm') {    
          ansiblePlaybook(
                 playbook: "test.yml",
                 inventory: "test-inventory.yml",
                 vaultCredentialsId: "ansible-vault-password",
                 extras: '-v',
                 tags: [
                     "test1",
                     "test2"
                     ],
                 extraVars: [
                     examplefname: "bob", 
                     exampleLname: "${PROFILE}", 
                     ],    
                 hostKeyChecking: false,
                 colorized: true
          )
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it would make much more sense to assign a `List<String>` value for the `tags` parameter like you did, the documentation does show the value should be a `String`. What the documentation does not explain is what the delimiter is for multiple tags. If we check the [Github repository README example snippet](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ansible-plugin#example) for the plugin, we see that the `tags` parameter String value should be comma delimited for multiple Ansible tags. For your specific use case, this parameter would appear like:

```
tags: 'test1,test2'
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt. it worked!